# Looping through Logistic Regression parameters to find best model, but can't replicate it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I built a loop to try to find the parameters that create the best model to predict my data:

```
## This just brute forces all options for different solvers, multi_class and max_iter since it seems those variables are what 
## affect prediction quality the most
penalty = ["l1", "l2", "elasticnet", "none"]
multi_class = ["auto", "ovr", "multinomial"]
logr_solver = ["newton-cg", "lbfgs", "liblinear", "sag", "saga"]
accuracylog_array = []
iter_multiplier = 5

for i in range(0,50):
    for solver in logr_solver:
        for mclass in multi_class:
            if solver == 'liblinear':
                logr = LogisticRegression(multi_class = 'auto', tol = 0.1, solver = solver, random_state=10, max_iter = i*iter_multiplier)

            else:
                logr = LogisticRegression(multi_class = mclass, tol = 0.1, solver = solver, random_state=10, max_iter = i*iter_multiplier)
            logr.fit(x_train, y_train)
            y_pred = logr.predict(x_train)
            y_pred2 = logr.predict(x_test)
            blah = y_pred2 - y_test.values
            c = sum(abs(i) for i in blah)
            accuracylog_array.append((len(blah) - c) / len(blah))
print("Max accuracy: ", np.max(accuracylog_array))
oos_logr_acc = np.max(accuracylog_array)
```

Output:

```
Max accuracy:  0.6231454005934718
```

I couldn't figure out a better way to find the model that produced the best accuracy other than just do all this math:

```
# Total model iterations
iterations = len(multi_class) * len(logr_solver) * 50
print("Iterations: ",iterations)

# Position of best model
modelpos = accuracylog_array.index(np.max(accuracylog_array))
print("Best model: ", modelpos)

# max_iter used in best model
max_iter_place = np.rint(modelpos / (len(multi_class) * len(logr_solver))) 
max_iterations = (max_iter_place - 1) * 5
print("Max_iter: ", max_iterations)

# multi_class used in best model
m_class_place = math.ceil((math.ceil(np.rint((modelpos / 15 - max_iterations / iter_multiplier) * 15) / len(logr_solver)))/len(logr_solver))-1
m_class = multi_class[m_class_place]
print("Multi_clas: ", m_class)

# solver used in best model
log_solver_place = modelpos - max_iter_place.astype(int) * len(multi_class) * len(logr_solver) + m_class_place * len(logr_solver) -1
log_solver_used = logr_solver[log_solver_place-1]
print("Solver used: ", log_solver_used)
```

Output:

```
Iterations:  750
Best model:  288
Max_iter:  90.0
Multi_clas:  auto
Solver used:  lbfgs
```

Problem is, when I then run the model with those parameters I get a worse accuracy:

```
# Define a variable called logr which contains a LogisticRegression(). Will use random_state = 10 across this paper. 
logr = LogisticRegression(multi_class = m_class, tol = 0.1, solver = log_solver_used, random_state=10, max_iter=max_iterations)

# Fit the model using the subset of train data within the training data. 
logr.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Get the predictions both in sample (using the x_train subset) and out of sample (using the x_test subset)
y_pred = logr.predict(x_train)
y_pred2 = logr.predict(x_test)
# Although MSE is not going to be our main loss function, we can obtain it to compare in sample and out of sample
print('Log Regression insample MSE:', mean_squared_error(y_train, y_pred))
print('Log Regression oos MSE:', mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred2))
print('Coefficients:', logr.coef_)
blah = y_pred2 - y_test.values
c = sum(abs(i) for i in blah)
accuracylogr = (len(blah) - c) / len(blah)
print('OOS Accuracy: ', accuracylogr)
```

Output:

```
Log Regression insample MSE: 0.41913946587537093
Log Regression oos MSE: 0.3857566765578635
Coefficients: [[-1.79035751e-02  1.68973579e-04  2.04467525e-02  5.53473743e-05
   5.27780069e-04 -5.47641843e-04 -6.02744053e-02 -7.46044781e-02
   9.17521781e-02  1.27247444e-01  7.65679676e-02 -6.41434613e-02
  -8.05893856e-04 -2.06843307e-03 -1.55544444e-03  1.94448408e-02
  -4.73256941e-02  2.70588013e-02 -1.85601461e-02  1.52533072e-02
  -9.64590787e-03 -2.10163742e-02  0.00000000e+00  1.62956948e-02
   4.52980738e-02  3.42300896e-02  2.93640162e-02  6.02024517e-02
   2.11497903e-02]]
OOS Accuracy:  0.6142433234421365
```

Im sure there must be a better way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Simply added an array that appends each models params while looping:

```
params_array.append(logr.get_params())
```

And then use the best model position to retrieve the right params:

```
# Total model iterations
iterations = len(multi_class) * len(logr_solver) * 50
print("Iterations: ",iterations)

# Position of best model
modelpos = accuracylog_array.index(np.max(accuracylog_array))
modelparams = params_array[modelpos]
print("Best model: ", modelpos)
print("Best model: ", modelparams)

# Params of the best model
m_class = modelparams['multi_class']
log_solver_used = modelparams['solver']
max_iterations = modelparams['max_iter']
```